# Stop thread immediately

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a long running task in a thread. I

```
Thread a = new Thread(new ThreadStart()({ delegate()
{
   Catalog.Generate(); //long running task
}));
a.Start();

Thread b = new Thread(new ThreadStart()({ delegate()
{
   if( File.Exists(stopFile) )
   {
       a.Abort();
    }
}));
b.Start();
```

This stops Thread A when the stop file is created BUT the catalog.generate method still keeps running? How do I end it?

Comment: BTW, I already tried BackgroundWorker, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your thread `b` starts working and does the check and immediately exits.

You have to add some sort of loop for the thread b to keep running (this is example code not best practice):

```
Thread b = new Thread(new ThreadStart()({ delegate()
{
   int t=0;
   while(i<100)
   { 

       if( File.Exists(stopFile) )
       {
           a.Abort();

        }
        else
        {
           i++;
           Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

}));
```

Comment: Sorry, there is already a while loop in Thread B (just forgot to copy it over).

Answer (score 0):

"Raises a ThreadAbortException in the thread on which it is invoked, to begin the process of terminating the thread. Calling this method usually terminates the thread."

The abort method sends an indicator that the thread should close. It is dependent on the thread processing as to how it handles this, and when it responds. I would suggest that the Catalog.Generate is probably refusing to respond.